# Set the min value in array of float with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array like below

```
array [0 => 1.0, 1 => 1.5, 2 => 3.0, 3 => 5.0, 4 => 7.5, 5 => 10.0, 6 => 20.0, 7 => 30.0, 8 => 50.0, 9 => 100.0]
```

I calculated a value like '6'. what i want to do is find the closest value of my table (that would be 5 in this case) and create a new array which have 5 for min value which would be this

```
array [0 => 5.0, 1 => 7.5, 2 => 10.0, 3 => 20.0, 4 => 30.0, 5 => 50.0, 6 => 100.0]
```

Is this possible to do this ?

Comment: is your array is always sorted?

Comment: yes, it's an array of value from the database

Comment: Seems pretty basic, create a function to iterate the array, if value is >= the comparing val add it to a new array then return said array...

Comment: I still need to determine the closest value before create the new array.

Comment: how does this `2 => 10.0` calculated?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: The bottom array is the top array minus all values that are below 5 (which is 3 items), causing the bottom array to have IDs shifted by -3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <?php
    $arr = [0 => 1.0, 1 => 1.5, 2 => 3.0, 3 => 5.0, 4 => 7.5, 5 => 10.0, 6 => 20.0, 7 => 30.0, 8 => 50.0, 9 => 100.0];

    var_dump( getNearestSequence($arr, 6) );

    function getNearestSequence($arr, $cue){
        $nextArray  = $arr;
        $arrOffsets = array();

        foreach($arr as $iKey=>$fVal){
            $arrOffsets[] = abs( doubleval($fVal - doubleval($cue)) ) . "";
        }

        $minVal     = min($arrOffsets);
        $arrOffFlip = array_flip($arrOffsets);
        $key        = $arrOffFlip[$minVal];
        array_splice($nextArray, 0, $key);
        return $nextArray;
    }

    // SINCE 5 IS CLOSEST TO 6 ON THE SEQUENCE; THIS DUMPS:   
        array (size=7)
          0 => float 5
          1 => float 7.5
          2 => float 10
          3 => float 20
          4 => float 30
          5 => float 50
          6 => float 100
```

Comment: what would you do if i need to get the next value ? that would be 7.5 in this case.

Comment: All you need to do is to change the Value of the 2nd Argument to reflect your wish. So for example if you want to get something next to 7 try this:
***var_dump( getNearestSequence($arr, 7) );*** Notice the ***7*** here. You just need to change that number to suit your requirements...

Comment: I misspelled my question. If i need the closest superior value. Like if $cue=11 get $nextArray = [ 0 => 20.0, 1 => 30.0, 2 => 50.0, 3 => 100.0];

Comment: It works like you explained. So if $cue is 11, then your array will start from 10.0 because ***11 is closer to 10 than it is to 20***. However if you change $cue to say: 16 then your array will start from 20.0 because ***16 is closest to 20.0 than it is to 10*** I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Yes i it's work fine like that i wanted in the beginning. But now i want to try something like the way i explained in the last comment. I'll gonna find another way for this case. Thank u very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your definition of *closest*, but here's one possible solution (assuming closest means the least mathematical difference between the numbers):

```
<?php
$number = 6; // this is your pre-determined number
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (isset($temp)) {
        if (abs($number - $value) <= abs($number - $temp)) {
            $temp = $value;
        }
    } else {
        $temp = $value;
    }
}
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value >= $temp) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT: This was written under the assumption that your initial array won't necessarily be sorted, and keys wouldn't necessarily be consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

use array_slice to rebuild the array

```
$array  =[1.0, 1.5, 3.0,  5.0,  7.5,  10.0,  20.0,  30.0,  50.0,  100.0];

$find = 6;
// init valuse with the 1st array item
$pos = 0;
$min = abs($array[0]-$find);
for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
   // because array is sorted we can stop iteration 
   // when abs($array[$i]-$find) begin increase
   if(abs($array[$i]-$find) > $min) break;
   // else save position and value
   else { $min = abs($array[$i]-$find); $pos = $i; }
}   

echo "Closest value : ". $array[$pos] . "\n";
$result = array_slice($array, $pos);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/563573)